# How to calculate work done when movement is not in the direction of the force?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, work, integration

I was trying to solve this problem:

[image]

but I encountred a problem while I was trying to evaluate the work done by $F$ over $AB$ which is:

$$ W= \int_{A}^{B} \vec{F}\cdot d\vec{s} $$

but how to compute this kind of integral? I tried to switch the variabe $d\vec{s}$ with $ Rd\theta$:
$$W= \int_{0}^{\pi/6} FR ~d\theta $$

but there isn't a function of $\theta$ inside the integral, so how to evaluate this integral?

Comment: Is math stack exchange more appropriate for this question?

Comment: This is called a [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_vector_field) and I don't see how it's supposed to be a physics question. Or, for that matter, how you managed to come across the notation $\int \vec F\cdot\mathrm{d}\vec s$ but not an explanation of what it denotes.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about the definition of a certain type of integral, not physics.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : I think you have exceeded your powers as a Moderator by closing this question. The [Help Center](http://physics.stackexchange.com/help/site-moderators) states that Moderators are **exception handlers** who close **blatantly off-topic questions**. This question is not blatantly off-topic and received no close votes other than your own. Please would you reconsider your decision and reopen this question.

Comment: @sammygerbil [It appears](http://physics.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/157839) that a majority of the reopen reviewers agreed with me that this question *is* blatantly off-topic - it's about the definition of a line integral, and the physical context given has exactly zero relevance to this; the question is pure math. (I did not migrate it to math.SE because I am almost certain it would be a duplicate there.) I am willing to reconsider my decision - if you make an argument what about this question makes it on-topic at physics.SE.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : see [this Meta post by JamalS](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/5713/). Current policy seems to be :"If the question is regarding a mathematical method applied to a physics problem, then it is appropriate for the physics SE." There is a clear physics background to this question. If it is a duplicate, none has been identified. None of the reviewers who cast "Leave Closed" votes had voted to close. Reviewers are reluctant to change the status of a question, and give the benefit of the doubt to current status.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : The question **might** have been closed by Reviewers had they been given the option. Your binding vote deprived them of that decision. That is my point : that you unilaterally closed a question which is not blatantly off topic. If it is not blatantly off topic, the question should be dealt with by the community in the Review Queues. I think the site policy on this is clear. ... I made the same complaint to DavidZ a few days ago. His response was to reopen the question. But I think he also deleted the comments and I cannot find the question.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : While the **title** is blatantly *off topic*, the **content** of the question (how to calculate work done) is not. I suggest that the Reviewers who voted to "Leave Closed" looked no further than the title. One Reviewer agreed with me; when my vote and yours are counted that is 4 v 2 in favour of "Leave Closed," although a majority this cannot be described as "blatant." See [How is the dot product a generalization of multiplication?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/251394) for a more "blatantly" pure math question which was not closed.

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the unit vector $[-\sin\theta,\cos\theta]$ along the path. In your integral $W= \int_{0}^{\pi/6} F\cdot R ~d\theta $, replace $F \cdot R ~d\theta$ by $R F\cdot [-\sin\theta,\cos\theta] ~d\theta$ and you are done ($F\cdot [-\sin\theta,\cos\theta] = -F_1\sin\theta+F_2\cos\theta$ for $F=[-F_1,F_2]$.)

Comment: and what is $ [ -sin \theta , cos \theta ] $ ? is it a vector ? if it's the case that means that I have to integrate a vector ???

Comment: Yes, it is a vector, and $F.[−\sin \theta,\cos \theta] = -F_1\sin \theta+F_2\cos \theta$. The end result is a scalar, not a vector.

Answer (score 1):

A particle is moving between points $\:\mathrm{A}\:$ and $\:\mathrm{B}\:$ of a  curve $\:C\:$ and a constant force $\:\mathbf{F}\:$ is applied continuously  on it. The work done by $\:\mathbf{F}\:$  between points $\:\mathrm{A}\:$ and $\:\mathrm{B}\:$ is ...

**On Plane**

[image]

**In Space**

[image]
[image]

**EDIT**

> OP asks : 
>   this means that the work done over AB is equal to the work done over the purple path in the Figure below?
>   [image]
>   Answer :
>   No, the work done over AB is equal to the work done over the green path AB', the projection of the curvilinear orbit (here: circular arc) AB on the direction of the constant force $\:\mathbf{F}\:$. This is valid for constant force vector. If the force is not constant in magnitude and/or direction then you must study about line integrals.

The purple path AB (segment) is the integral :
$$
\int\limits_{\rm{arc\:AB}} \mathrm{d}\mathbf{s}
$$

Comment: Jan Lalinsky's comment seems to have disappeared, leaving your reference to it meaningless. Best to reproduce comments if you quote them, because they are liable to be removed by the author or a Moderator.

Comment: @sammy gerbil : Happy New Year. Thanks for your attention. The deleted Ján Lalinský's comment was this one : _The scalar product $\:\overrightarrow{F}\cdot \overrightarrow{ds}\:$ can be expressed as $\:F\cdot ds'$, where $\:ds'\:$ is horizontal component of the displacement $\: \overrightarrow{ds}$. Then integrate over $\:s'$._ I think the deletion was done by moderator due to the policy "don't post answers in comments". Anyway, I deleted this reference in my answer.

Comment: To the user who downvoted my answer without a comment to explain why : I don't care so much about reputation so continue downvoting.

Comment: Perhaps the down-voter did not get a pair of 3D goggles in his/her Christmas Stocking, so is not able to appreciate your 2nd diagram!

Comment: @sammy gerbil : I accept downvoting by a user but I wish to have his comment explaining why. I suspect that this downvote is done by a moderator who reasonably has not time to explain. In such  a case I understand  the absence of an explanation comment.

Comment: Yes, it is rude not to give a reason. It ought to be a requirement.

Comment: I would like to emphasize my stand here (its better suited at the meta site). Down voting without proper reasoning should not be allowed. " I suspect that this down vote is done by a moderator who reasonably has not time to explain."- Then the moderator should down vote when he has got time.

Comment: this means that the work done over AB is equal to the work done over the purple path ? (see the link ) :    https://postimg.org/image/hxjiy9rqx/

Comment: @Mamadou : No, the work done over AB is equal to the work done over the green path AB', the projection of the curvilinear orbit (here: circular arc) AB on the direction of the constant force $\:\mathbf{F}\:$. This is valid for constant force vector. If the force is not constant in magnitude and/or direction then you must study about line integrals. I edit my answer for your question.